# Powershell - fast way of searching files based on rules

Tags: powershell

Mainly looking for some pointers and a little bit of code.  The task I have is to search through a number of files for different strings and create a log of the matches.

Initially I was parsing through each file looking for a single string but it was too slow once I had thousands of files around 1MB each.  I therefore would like to try opening each file once and scan the file for multiple strings, attributing them in a log to the various rules.

I have created the following rules file:

```
{"Logs": {
   "Component":
   {
     "Files":[
       {
         "name": "test.txt",
         "encoding": "UTF8",
         "rules":[{
           "Rule1":"this is text"
           }]
       },
       {
         "name": "test2.txt",
         "encoding": "UTF8",
         "rules":[{
            "Rule2": "this is text1",
            "Rule3": "this is text3"
            }]
       }
     ]
   }
}}
```

Maybe that needs to be improved and can be changed. The following Powershell uses the rule to go searching through files:

```
Function ParseFile($Files){
write-host "Parsing file" $Files.Name "for text " $Files.rules

 Get-ChildItem "." -Recurse -Filter $Files.Name | 
   Foreach-Object {
     write-host $_.FullName

     Foreach($line in Get-Content $_.FullName -encoding $Files.encoding ) {

     ##Check if the current line from file matches a rule from the $Files.Rules array.
     ##If so log the file, line and rule ID to a CSV file. E.g.:
     ##RuleID, RuleString, LineFromFile, FileName

     }
   } 
}

$JSON = Get-Content -Raw -Path rule.json | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($files in $JSON.Logs.Component.Files  ){
  write-host $files.name
  write-host "============================="
  ParseFile $files
}
```

Does the above make sense for the quickest way to search and classify?
I'm not sure quite how to approach the commented section.  I assume $line -in $Files.rules but I don't think the array is quite right for this.

Any suggestions welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to this. Personally I would start with loop and use `-like` (see solution from @boxdog)  until you understand PowerShell and the solution better. If you want to optimize it later, I would suggest constructing a switch-statement or regex-pattern (using group names to identify the rule) dynamically for each File-entry. They will perform better, but are more advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative using regex. I modified the JSON to make it easier to parse. The original JSON can work if needed by getting RuleID and RuleString using name and value properties in `$_.rules.psobject.properties`.

This solution requires `RuleID` to be single word.

rules.json

```
{"Logs": {
    "Component":
    {
        "Files":[
        {
            "name": "test.txt",
            "encoding": "UTF8",
            "rules":[{
                "RuleID": "Rule1",
                "Rule": "this is text"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "test2.txt",
            "encoding": "UTF8",
            "rules":[
            {
                "RuleID": "Rule2",
                "Rule": "this is text1"
            },
            {
                "RuleID": "Rule3",
                "Rule": "this is text3"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
}}
```

Code:

```
$JSON.Logs.Component.Files | ForEach-Object {
    $item = $_

    #Create regex-pattern
    $pattern = ($item.rules | ForEach-Object { "(?'$($_.RuleID)'$([regex]::Escape($_.Rule)))" }) -join '|'

    #Find matching files
    Get-ChildItem -Path "." -Recurse -Filter $item.Name |
    Select-String -Pattern $pattern -Encoding $item.Encoding -AllMatches |
    ForEach-Object {

        $MatchedRule = $_.Matches.Groups | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne '0' -and $_.Success }

        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            RuleID = $MatchedRule.Name
            RuleString = $MatchedRule.Value
            LineFromFile = $_.Line
            FileName = $_.Path
        }

    }
} | Export-Csv -Path results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

results.csv:

```
"FileName","LineFromFile","RuleID","RuleString"
"D:\New folder\test.txt","foo this is text1 bar","Rule1","this is text"
"D:\New folder\test.txt","this is text3ss","Rule1","this is text"
"D:\New folder\test2.txt","foo this is text1 bar","Rule2","this is text1"
"D:\New folder\Test\test2.txt","this is text3ss","Rule3","this is text3"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide the answer.  I haven't had any time to fully test it but from your result output it looks good. You were right, the rule name is important for what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted your JSON slightly:

```
{"Logs": {
   "Component":
   {
     "Files":[
       {
         "name": "test.txt",
         "encoding": "UTF8",
         "rules":["this is text"
         ]
       },
       {
         "name": "test2.txt",
         "encoding": "UTF8",
         "rules":["this is text1",
          "this is text3"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
}}
```

Using this, here is a possible solution:

```
$JSON = Get-Content -Raw -Path rules.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$JSON.Logs.Component.Files |
    ForEach-Object {
        $fileName = $_.Name
        $rules = $_.rules

        Get-Content $fileName -encoding $_.encoding |
            ForEach-Object {
                for($i=0;$i -lt $rules.Count;$i++)
                {
                    if($_ -like "*$($rules[$i])*")
                    {
                        [PsCustomObject]@{RuleNumber = ($i+1); 
                                          RuleString = $rules[$i];
                                          MatchingText = $_;
                                          File = $filename} | 
                            Export-Csv matches.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: This neglects OP's requirement of outputting the rule id in the output

Comment: If the rules are all just called ‘rule1’, ‘rule2’, etc as in the question, then you still get the 1,2,etc to identify them by.  If the names don’t have this simple pattern, then, yes, this will need re-worked.

Comment: They were probably fake names. If you're first going to modify the JSON, why not make the rules objects with a RuleID and Rule property? That way it would be clean and easy to get both. Using the original JSON, you could loop the properties of `Groups` with `Get-Member` or `...Groups.psobject.properties` and use name/value to access the ID and rule

Comment: @boxdog: Thank you for the reply.  I was looking at getting the names of the rules.  Kind regards.